# Green-Tao theorem consequence is not contradictory? Why?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

According to the Green–Tao theorem:

> there exist arbitrarily long sequences of primes in arithmetic progression.

However, one of the properties of Green-Tao theorem is:

> Any given arithmetic progression of primes has a finite length.

I can only read two contradictory sentences. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know the Green-Tao theorem but the two statements are not contradictory. The first one says "you give me a number and I give you an arithmetic progression of primes of that length or longer". The second one says there is no infinitely long arithmetic progression of primes, namely they all terminate at some point.

Comment: They are contradictory because there are infinite numbers. So second cannot be true if first is true.

Comment: There can be an arithmetic progression of primes of a length of one trillion but there is none that goes on forever.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem says that, for each $n$, there is a sequence of $n$ primes in arithmetic progression. This in no way contradicts the fact that there is no infinite arithmetic sequence such that all of its terms are prime numbers.

Comment: What you say is what I can read from my post. But for me the two sentences are contradictory. They are saying exactly the opposite to my understanding. My question is what am I missing that I just see that both sentences say the opposite?

Comment: You seem to believe that if there is an arithmetic sequence with $2$ prime numbers, an arithmetic sequence with $3$ prime numbers, an arithmetic sequence with $4$ prime numbers and so on, then there has to be an arithmetic sequence with infinitely many prime numbers. Is that it?

Comment: What you are missing (which is implicit in José’s answer) is that the sequences of each length are different. So one sequence is an AP of length 2, a different one is an AP of length 3 etc. But there is no SINGLE AP that keeps going on and on forever.

Answer (score 0):

These statements mean that for any number $n$, there are infinitely many arithmetic progressions composed entirely of primes, with no primes between consecutive members of the progression, of length at least $n$.

It does not mean that there exist arithmetic progressions of infinite length comprised only of primes – it is easy to show that no such progression exists by simple modular arithmetic.